# If $f$ is differentiable and $f'(a)<0$, is $f$ decreasing on some interval around $a$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Refer to this question (answer of Rick) :[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1545090/if-fa0fb-then-there-is-c-such-that-fc-0/1545093?noredirect=1#comment3146470_1545093)

The question let $f:[r,s]\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ continuous on $[r,s]$ and differentiable on $(r,s)$. Suppose $f'(a)<0<f'(b)$. Show that there is a $c$ s.t. $f'(c)=0$.

In it's answer, Rick says that by continuity there is a $\delta>0$ s.t. $[a,a-\delta]$ is decreasing. By Marc McClure, it's a wrong argument, but I can't find a counter example neither prove that the argument is correct. Does someone can give me a counter example or prove it ?

Comment: Think *wiggles*. That is, take some decreasing function, say $x\mapsto-x$, and perturb it by an oscillating function, small enough to leave the derivative unchanged but whose derivative takes nonvanishing values destroying the monotonicity. For example, $$f(x)=-x+2x^2\sin(1/x).$$

Comment: Any Weierstrass function will do.

Comment: *At $a=0$, of course.

Comment: @did: nice couter example :-) tks,